# DAX - company's weights

Tags: index

How often are company's weights being changed on DAX?

Where can I find historical data of DAX weights?

Comment: The composition is reviewed quarterly. The weights are given here but only to 2009 http://www.dax-indices.com/EN/index.aspx?pageID=4 . Look for files called "Composition DAX"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A committee at the exchange reviews the composition of the DAX quarterly. In practice there are relatively few and infrequent changes. Current and past weights are given here dax-indices.com/EN/index.aspx?pageID=4 , but the old data only goes back to 2009. Look for spreadsheet files called "Composition DAX".